# session fixation, still an issue with register_globals off?

Tags: php, session-fixation, register-globals

I've been reading into some articles about PHP security, and I came across this article:
http://shiflett.org/articles/session-fixation

This article describes that one can easily fixate a session by passing the PHPSESSID variable in a url request (for example `?PHPSESSID=1234`). However, it is my understanding (and please correct me if I am wrong) that PHP treats `$_GET`, `$_SESSION` and `$GLOBALS` as different types of variables when `register_globals` is set to `off` in php.ini, and therefor using `?PHPSESSID=1234` in a url request should not produce this problem.

I have tested the following script:

```
session_start(); 

if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) 
{ 
   $_SESSION['count'] = 0; 
} 
else 
{ 
   $_SESSION['count']++; 
} 

echo $_SESSION['count'];
```

But I can't seem to reproduce the fixation of sessions on my server, and I assumed it is because I have `register_globals` set to `off` in my php.ini.
Am I wrong about this?
It seems important to know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a separate php config option, I think `session.use_trans_sid`, that allows the session to be passed via url regardless of register_global setting.